# Extension of representations of certain compact Lie groups

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a real, connected, non-compact, semisimple Lie group with finite center and real rank $1$. Let $G=KAN$ be an Iwasawa decomposition, then  $K\subset G$ is a maximal compact subgroup, and $\dim A=1$ (which is the definition of the real rank of $G$ being $1$). Let $M:=Z_K(A)$ be the centralizer of $A$ in $K$. Note that $M$ is a compact subgroup of $G$, being a closed subgroup of $K$.

Let $\tau:M\to \mathrm{End}(V)$  be a finite-dimensional complex representation of $M$. Then I would like to know: **Under which circumstances does there exist a finite-dimensional complex representation of $K$ that extends $\tau$?**

I searched for quite a long time now, and all literature about extension of representations of compact Lie groups only deals with *normal* subgroups. However, $M$ need not be normal in $K$ in general.

Comment: One of the older references which might (or might not) be helpful here is the set of lecture notes David Collingwood wrote after his lecture series in Argentina:   *Representations of rank one Lie groups* (Pitman, 1985).   These notes often discuss special cases, which can be illuminating in view of the sophisticated underlying general theory here.

Comment: In case I haven't misunderstood your question, you are looking for branching laws from $K$ to $M$. When $\dim A=1$, these branching laws (depending of $G=SO(n,1), SU(n,1), Sp(n,1), F_4$) should be known.